# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for with id that does not autoincrement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a model `B` whose primary key `id` does not auto-increment (because its values are guids from another system).

I get an error when I try to create a *new* instance of `B` by setting nested attributes:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find B with ID=076dda41-afa6-4324-b6fd-219d99089dfc for A with ID=846205`

```rb
a.attributes = {
  b_attributes: {
    id: '076dda41-afa6-4324-b6fd-219d99089dfc'
  }
}
```

How can I make the assignment build a new instance of `B` when I specify an id?

*This project is on Rails 4.0.1*

Answer (score 0):

You can refer one of the samples [here](https://github.com/AquisTech/expense_tracker/blob/master/app/controllers/transaction_purposes_controller.rb#L15)
Even I am doing some sort of manipulation.

What I mainly suspecting is `id` attribute.

In nested attributes, when you pass hash without `id` then it is considered new record and it is created.
When you pass `id` it tries to find the record to be updated.
When you pass `_destroy` it is marked for destruction.

Workaround that I could think of is:

1. Try making `id` column NOT primary key so that Rails won't try finding existing record. But in that case you will need to take care of update part.
   OR
2. Create a new column `guid` where you will have this identifier and maintain `id` column as Rails default one. Just that setup all the associations on `guid`